# Merge content of two columns with parenthesis in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, sorting, matrix

I have a dataset like this

```
structure(list(x1 = c("red", "green", "blue", "blue"), x2 = c(60, 
10, 50, 50), x3 = c("blue", "red", "red", "green"), x4 = c(30, 
30, 40, 30)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to merge red with 60, blue with 30 and so on for each row, so that I will only have two columns like this

[image]

How do I **merge the two columns** and how do I put the **numbers in brackets**?

Comment: Use `paste0`. Something like `data.frame(x1 = paste0(df$x1, " (", df$x2, ")"), x2 = paste0(df$x3, " (", df$x4, ")"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `glue::glue` makes things easier when we have to dynamically generate strings, so we can avoid multi-argument calls to `paste`, as in `paste(x, y, z ....)`. I feel it makes it easier to anticipate the output of glue just by looking into it's arguments.

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

df %>% 
    mutate(x1 = glue("{x1} ({x2})"),
           x2 = glue("{x3} ({x4})"),
           .keep = 'none')

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x1         x2        
  <glue>     <glue>    
1 red (60)   blue (30) 
2 green (10) red (30)  
3 blue (50)  red (40)  
4 blue (50)  green (30)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = paste0(x1, " (", x2, ")"),
         x2 = paste0(x3, " (", x4, ")")) %>% 
  select(x1, x2)


# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x1         x2        
  <chr>      <chr>     
1 red (60)   blue (30) 
2 green (10) red (30)  
3 blue (50)  red (40)  
4 blue (50)  green (30)
```

Comment: No need of `select`. This is one of the better use of `transmute` instead of `mutate` or use `mutate(...,.keep = 'none')`

Comment: minor quibble, @onyambu. From the changelog from dplyr 1.1.0 release: "transmute() is superseded in favour of mutate(.keep = "none") (#6414)."

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyover`

```
library(dplyover)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  transmute(over(c(1, 3), ~ sprintf('%s (%d)', .("x{.x}"),
       .("x{.x+1}")), .names = "x{x_idx}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x1         x2        
  <chr>      <chr>     
1 red (60)   blue (30) 
2 green (10) red (30)  
3 blue (50)  red (40)  
4 blue (50)  green (30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that Jilber Urbina has answered, but I'd like to put two coins on it with `R base`, so you don't need to use other packages (like "dplyr" in this case).

```
# This is your data
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("red", "green", "blue", "blue"), 
               x2 = c(60, 10, 50, 50), 
               x3 = c("blue", "red", "red", "green"), 
               x4 = c(30, 30, 40, 30))
# foo is a function that returns "v1 (v2)", where "vi" is "variable i".
foo <- function(v1,v2) paste0(v1, " (",v2,")")
# let's use this function
df$x1 <- foo(df$x1,df$x2)
df$x3 <- foo(df$x3,df$x4)
# drop the other variables
df$x2 <- df$x4 <- NULL
#your expected data
> df
          x1         x3
1   red (60)  blue (30)
2 green (10)   red (30)
3  blue (50)   red (40)
4  blue (50) green (30)
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is in fact very useful as I am trying to learn as much R as possible! It is very important to me to learn functions so thank you